# I am trying to select a value which is in the 2nd index from dropdown and compare it with the value fetched from excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium, webdriver

```
List <WebElement> elementCount = dropdown.getOptions();
System.out.println(elementCount.size());
for(int i=0;i<elementCount.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println("Value of i is: "+i);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(dri10,500+(elementCount.size()*500));
    WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("Select Role")));
    dropdown.selectByIndex(i);                  //when the value of i becomes 2 an exception is displayed
    Thread.sleep(100+(elementCount.size()*400)); 
    String approle=dri10.findElement(By.id("Select Role")).getText();
    String assigrole=s1.getCell(3,16).getContents();            //Fetching data from excel
    if(approle.equals(assigrole))
    {
        dri10.findElement(By.id("Submenu")).click();
    }
}
```

Exception Details: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 146 milliseconds

Comment: The exception that am getting is "org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 146 milliseconds"

Comment: Can you print the stacktrace where exactly you are getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown when there are js updates on your element.
To avoid this exception, I usually surround my code with :

```
try{
    //some code
}catch (StaleElementReferenceException e){
    //retry it
}
```

I created some functions to avoid it. You can retry multiple time if the app is calling js multiple time also.